# product of all elements in subsets of timeseries

Tags: list-manipulation, time-series

apologies in advance if this is obvious, but I'm very new to mathematica and couldn't find the answer in the documentation nor in the forum here...

I've got a 2 year time series ts with daily percentage returns of a particular stock and want to create a table showing monthly total returns.

```
MonthlyAvReturns = Table[Mean[TimeSeriesWindow[ts, {{y, m, 1}, {y, m, 31}}]],{y,2015, 2016}, {m, 1, 12}]
```

The above gives me the average value of the data for each month. To get monthly returns, I'd need to multiply those values instead of adding them with `Total[]`.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this than doing this manually via

```
JanReturns = TimeSeriesWindow[ts,{{2015, 1, 1}, {2015, 1, 31}}];
Times@@(JanReturns["Values"]+1)
```

Any pointers would be extremely welcome. Thanks in advance!

Also - this is a custom return series, so nothing that can be downloaded through `FinancialData["ticker","CumulativeFractionalChange","dates"]`.

Comment: What's wrong with replacing `Mean` with your `Times@@(1+Values[...])`?

Comment: If I do that, I get the error message:

 "Times@@" cannot be followed by "[TimeSeriesWindow[ts,{{y,m,1},{y,m,31}}]]".